# Can OptaPlanner Facts include Planning Entity objects?

Tags: optaplanner

Can an OptaPlanner Fact include an Planning Entity?  My guess is that the answer is no because it would violate the rule that facts cannot change.

If this indeed is supported, I'm encountering a null pointer exception when attempting to invoke the getter method.

Here's the rule, school1 is a private variable of the Parings fact that contains an associated Planning Entity.

```html
   when
        Run($r : runId)
        Pairings(runId1 == $r, $s1 : school1.adjustment.timeAdjustment)  ...
```

Here's the stack trace.

```html
Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule "maximizeLiftPairings" in org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke getter: getSchool1 [declr.class: org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Pairings; act.class: org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Pairings] (see trace)
 at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
 at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1027)
 at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:128)
 at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:70)
 at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:935)
 at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1200)
 at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:957)
 at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:931)
 at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:256)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsScoreDirector.java:98)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.calculateScore(DefaultSolverScope.java:101)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.bestsolution.BestSolutionRecaller.solvingStarted(BestSolutionRecaller.java:58)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:177)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:154)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.app.CloudBalancingHelloWorld.main(CloudBalancingHelloWorld.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke getter: getSchool1 [declr.class: org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Pairings; act.class: org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.Pairings] (see trace)
 at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:74)
 at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:108)
 at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)
 at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
 at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
 at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:954)
 at org.drools.core.base.extractors.MVELNumberClassFieldReader.getValue(MVELNumberClassFieldReader.java:102)
 at org.drools.core.rule.Declaration.getValue(Declaration.java:229)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.Rule_maximizeLiftPairings143464364DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.Rule_maximizeLiftPairings143464364DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
 at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1016)
 ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to invoke method: org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.School.getAdjustment: target of method is null
 at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:66)
 at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:40)
 ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:40)
 ... 24 more
```

Comment: Your stack trace says that the null pointer exception is from the fact that it can't invoke `getAdjustment`. I'm guessing `Adjustment` is the planning entity?

Comment: Actually, it's school1 that contains the planning entity.  It appears that there's an answer already to this question that confirms by suspicion.

Comment: I see, no wonder this was thrown : `java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke getter: getSchool1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for the record. Bruce's answer is better in essence :)

**It's possible**, but in most cases, **it's not recommended**. There are some pitfalls. There are 2 ways:

A) Turn that problem fact class into a shadow planning entity class. A shadow planning entity class is a class with only shadow planning variables (so no genuine planning variables). Of course, make sure to register that class in the solver config and annotate it properly. But in this case, it should pretty much work (including planning cloning etc).

B) Hack it (not recommended!). Keep it as a problem fact class, but customize the planning cloner so it get planning cloned (because it won't get cloned by default probably). Make sure you first clearly understand what "planning clone" means (see docs). It's not a shallow clone, it's not a deep clone, it's something in between (with logic depending on planning annotations etc). This hack will be hard+painful to implement correctly (and might not be future proof).

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch was right, the answer is **no**.

From the **[documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Beta2/optaplanner-docs/html/plannerConfiguration.html#d0e2025)**:

> In OptaPlanner all problems facts and planning entities are plain old JavaBeans (POJO's). You can load them from a database (JDBC/JPA/JDO), an XML file, a data repository or even a noSQL cloud. OptaPlanner doesn't care.

**Planning Entity:**

> A planning entity is a JavaBean (POJO) that **changes during solving**, for example a Queen that changes to another row. A planning problem has multiple planning entities, for example for a single n queens problem, each Queen is a planning entity. But there's usually only 1 planning entity class, for example the Queen class.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Queen {


private Column column;


// Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations.

private Row row;


// ... getters and setters

}
```

**Problem Fact:**

> A problem fact is any JavaBean (POJO) with getters that **does not change during planning**. Implementing the interface Serializable is recommended (but not required). For example in n queens, the columns and rows are problem facts:

```
public class Column implements Serializable {


private int index;


// ... getters

}
```